# Is there a more efficient way to authenticate a teams bot with Microsoft graph in an azure function when the bot is used by multiple organizations?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm looking to create a Microsoft Teams chat bot that sends an API call to an azure function which auths into the Graph API using an appID and secret specific to the organization that the Teams bot is running on. The bot sends an email to a hardcoded address from the user who sent the message.

Problems:

- I need a way to pass in sensitive unique app IDs and secrets to the azure function based on the organization
- Assuming I can pass the values uniquely, making an API call to generate a bearer token takes awhile (a few whole seconds). Once I have the bearer token the graph API call to send the email is near-instant. I'd like to trim the few seconds off of the response time when authing for the bearer token if possible. Keeping the bearer token saved somewhere isn't worth it because it will likely expire before the user calls the application next.

What I have so far:

- A bot that works successfully end to end in an emulator and auths using a hardcoded appID, secret, endpoint, and user GUID (since the emulator GUID doesn't exist in the org, but I can get it dynamically when it's deployed).
- The bot sends the auth API the secret and app id, then sends another api call to send the email using the bearer token received in the response from the last API call.

Comment: why don't you maintain id and secrets in config file and based on some key validate them and get your id and secrets rather than sending it in api call.

Comment: That helps, for each client I can have a key and the value will be the id and secret. It will still take while to wait API call to turn those into a bearer token which is needed to make the second API call. I don't think caching the bearer token is an option here.

Comment: There should be some other issue in code probably. because Auth api's are quick enough. Are you looking at cutting down those 1 or 2 seconds that api takes to get token? if yes, that's not possible. Check if [SSO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-aad-sso) helps.